# Can disk diffuson be used, without diluting a broth culture to match a 0.5 McFarland turbidity standard?

Tags: microbiology, experimental-design, antibiotic-resistance

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np87w5kCL-4&ab_channel=GreatDiseases), there doesn't seem to be a process of diluting the broth. I'm not looking for extremely accurate test results, all I need is to see if a particular colony is susceptible to the antibiotic. Since it's not a lab project or anything, I only need a Yes or No answer. Does that mean broth dilution can be substituted by making a good lawn? Can I just inoculate my agar that simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "susceptible" for the question that you're asking. Fresh broth cultures will likely give you a good lawn, but if you aren't doing anything to standardize the innoculum, it's not really comparable to anything else when you make your determination. So, if you do end up seeing a zone of inhibition, you won't really have any idea if it's actually suceptible in the context of clinical relevance. For that, you'd check a table of [clinical breakpoints](https://www.eucast.org/fileadmin/src/media/PDFs/EUCAST_files/Breakpoint_tables/v_12.0_Breakpoint_Tables.pdf) for that organism, which are determined using [standardized protocols](https://asm.org/getattachment/2594ce26-bd44-47f6-8287-0657aa9185ad/Kirby-Bauer-Disk-Diffusion-Susceptibility-Test-Protocol-pdf.pdf) most likely involving a McFarland standard. If you look through the linked table of breakpoints, you'll find that some organisms can have a fairly large ZOI diameter and still be considered resistant.

Another consideration is spontaneus plasmid loss. In my experience, passaging a colony into a broth culture overnight is a great way to cure plasmids from their host, plasmids that may carry genes which would otherwise make your isolate resistant to antibiotics. For that reason alone, I think you're better off using some kind of pseudo-McFarland procedure than broth cultures. If you don't have a standard, and don't want to buy one, just pick some colony and mix it up in a mL or so of sterile saline solution until it's a little more turbid than the unadulterated saline solution and make the lawn with that (looking up pictures of the different standards online will probably get you in the ballpark, which is really all the McFarland standard method is anyway).